# How to Overcome MDX Query Error When It Can't Find Specific Entity

Tags: entity, mdx, cube, dimensions, iccube

When i run MDX query  like:

```
select {[Measures].[all_accounts]} ON COLUMNS,

{{[Country].[Country].[Country].&[italy]}*
{[TD].[TD].[date].&[2016-09-02T03:00:00.000]:[TD].[TD].[date].&[2016-09-02T03:08:00.000]},
{[Country].[Country].[Country].&[Germany]}*
{[TD].[TD].[date].&[2016-08-16T04:00:00.000]:[TD].[TD].[date].&[2016-08-16T04:03:00.000]}}

ON ROWS

FROM [cube]
```

i get an error because 'italy' is not an entity found in Country dimension.
and no result is coming back.

i want to be able to run the mdx without necessarily knowing the entities names in the dimension and get back a result only for those that exists. in this example 'Germany'. how can i overcome this problem?

Comment: It's not an uppercase/lowercase issue ( keys are case sensitive) ?  &[Italy] ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the configuration of the server, [icCube.xml](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/user_guide/configuring_iccube/iccube_xml.php), to convert not found members to null (it's risky).

[icCube.mdxEvalUnknownMemberError](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/icCubeDefaultXmlaProperties.php)

If you do not want to change this setting for the whole server you can use an annotation with each MDX query. For example, the following query will not return anything for the missing &[_FR] member:

```
//#prop( icCube.mdxEvalUnknownMemberError = false )
select { 
  [Geography].[Geo].[Country].&[FR_], 
  [Geography].[Geo].[Country].&[US] 
} on 0 from [Sales]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a very positive answer I'm afraid but if you use member unique names such as `[Country].[Country].[Country].&[italy]` in a script then you will get an error if that member is not in the cube ... I don't believe there is a workaround.

I have to add that this 'limitation' has never caused me a problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. although i still need to figure out a solution :)