# icCube Multilevel Hierarchy - sometimes not all alternate values are present, how to overcome the 'unexpected error'?

Tags: iccube

I've defined a multilevel hierarchy with an alternative roll-up. The alternative roll-up is based on pre-defined KPI values, and I expect all values to be present.

I use the KPI values to create a CATEGORY and base several charts on this category. But if not all expected KPI values are present, the CATEGORY member, when used in the dashboards, gives me the error '... is not a known MDX entity'.

**Question:
How can I solve the "unexpected error: ... is not a known MDX entity" which pops-up in the dashboards when a KPI value is not present.**

Consider the following picture with an example:
[image: example illustrating the issue]

**This is what I tried so far**

1. Tried the MDX function RemoveUnknown, but that is something else than removing a "not known MDX entity", https://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/RemoveUnknown.php
2. The solution from https://stackoverflow.com/a/39616281/2882924, but it does not work when creating categories, nor when querying categories. The error remains.
3. Always add 4 rows with the KPI values to the datasource. It works, but you end up with 4 dummy values, which gives other problems.